# document:keydown.control.ArrowRight can not work in mac google browser

Tags: angular

code is here:

```
import { Component, VERSION, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.full;
  
  @HostListener('document:keydown.control.ArrowRight', ["$event"])
  demoFn(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('jimmy')
  }
}
```

can not print log message in mac google browser, but can do in window browser.

Comment: But when i use ```document:keydown.control.shift.arrowright```, It work. It is interesting~